# Exclude a button in Salesforce1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, ui

I have a lightning page which is the entry page to my org. It includes a button "Enter" which redirects to the Org's home page. It works perfectly. But in Salesforce1, I have no use for it. How can I exclude only that button in the  Salesforce1 UI ?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to add code to your visualforce page that detects the "user experience theme" your page is being rendered in, then conditionally render the button. If the theme detected is "Theme4t" (Salesforce1 mobile theme), you'll want to set the value for rendering the button to `false`. See [Share Visualforce Pages Between Classic and Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/units/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages) from the [Visualforce & Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_visualforce) Module in Trailhead.